# Getting very long "No match for 'operator+'" error in C++

Tags: c++

I'm out of practice with C++ and am writing a "Bank" class for a course I'm taking.  I'm getting a long error every time I attempt to compile my Bank.cpp file.  I suspect I'm missing something quite obvious here, but I don't know what because the error doesn't make any sense to me.

Here's the cpp file I'm writing that won't compile:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Bank.h"

Bank::Bank(): savings(0), checking(0) { }

Bank::Bank(double savings_amount, double checking_amount): savings(savings_amount), checking(checking_amount) { }

void Bank::deposit(double amount, string account)
{
        if (account == "S") {
                savings = savings + amount;
        } else {
                checking += amount;
        }
}

void Bank::withdraw(double amount, string account)
{
        if (account == "S") {
                savings -= amount;
        } else {
                checking -= amount;
        }
}

void Bank::transfer(double amount, string account)
{
        if (account == "S") {
                savings -= amount;
                checking += amount;
        } else {
            checking -= amount;
        }
}

void Bank::transfer(double amount, string account)
{
        if (account == "S") {
                savings -= amount;
                checking += amount;
        } else {
                checking -= amount;
                savings += amount;
        }
}

void Bank::print_balances()
{
        cout << "Savings: $ " << savings;
        cout << "Checking: $ " << checking;
}
```

Here's the header file:

```
#ifndef BANK_H
#define BANK_H

#include <string>

#include "Account.h"

using namespace std;

class Bank {
private:
    Account savings;
    Account checking;
public:
    Bank();
    Bank(double savings_amount, double checking_amount);
    void deposit(double amount, string account);
    void withdraw(double amount, string account);
    void transfer(double amount, string account);
    void print_balances();
};

#endif
```

And here's the "Account.h" header file that is referenced at the top:

```
#ifndef ACCOUNT_H
#define ACCOUNT_H


class Account {
private:
    double balance;
    double interest_rate;
public:
    Account();
    Account(double amount, double rate);
    void deposit(double);
    bool withdraw(double);
    double query();
    void set_interest_rate(double rate);
    double get_interest_rate();
    void add_interest();
};

#endif
```

And here is the cryptic error I'm receiving:

> Bank.cpp: In member function ‘void Bank::deposit(double, std::string)’:
>   Bank.cpp:17: error: no match for ‘operator+’ in ‘((Bank*)this)->Bank::savings + amount’
>   Bank.cpp:19: error: no match for ‘operator+=’ in ‘((Bank*)this)->Bank::checking += amount’
>   Bank.cpp: In member function ‘void Bank::withdraw(double, std::string)’:
>   Bank.cpp:26: error: no match for ‘operator-=’ in ‘((Bank*)this)->Bank::savings -= amount’
>   Bank.cpp:28: error: no match for ‘operator-=’ in ‘((Bank*)this)->Bank::checking -= amount’
>   Bank.cpp: In member function ‘void Bank::transfer(double, std::string)’:
>   Bank.cpp:35: error: no match for ‘operator-=’ in ‘((Bank*)this)->Bank::savings -= amount’
>   Bank.cpp:36: error: no match for ‘operator+=’ in ‘((Bank*)this)->Bank::checking += amount’
>   Bank.cpp:38: error: no match for ‘operator-=’ in ‘((Bank*)this)->Bank::checking -= amount’
>   Bank.cpp:39: error: no match for ‘operator+=’ in ‘((Bank*)this)->Bank::savings += amount’
>   Bank.cpp: In member function ‘void Bank::print_balances()’:
>   Bank.cpp:45: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::operator<< [with _Traits = std::char_traits](((std::basic_ostream >&)(& std::cout)), ((const char*)"Savings: $ ")) << ((Bank*)this)->Bank::savings’
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:108: note: candidates are: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:117: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:127: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:165: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:169: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:173: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(bool) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/ostream.tcc:91: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:180: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/ostream.tcc:105: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:191: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:200: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:204: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:209: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(double) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:213: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(float) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:221: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long double) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:225: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(const void*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/ostream.tcc:119: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   Bank.cpp:46: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::operator<< [with _Traits = std::char_traits](((std::basic_ostream >&)(& std::cout)), ((const char*)"Checking: $ ")) << ((Bank*)this)->Bank::checking’
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:108: note: candidates are: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:117: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:127: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:165: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:169: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:173: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(bool) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/ostream.tcc:91: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:180: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/ostream.tcc:105: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:191: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:200: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:204: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:209: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(double) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:213: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(float) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:221: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long double) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:225: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(const void*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/ostream.tcc:119: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   [004709613@jb359-5 Lab1]$ Bank.cpp: In member function ‘void Bank::deposit(double, std::string)’:
>   -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
>   [004709613@jb359-5 Lab1]$ Bank.cpp:17: error: no match for ‘operator+’ in ‘((Bank*)this)->Bank::savings + amount’
>   -bash: syntax error near unexpected token`('
>   [004709613@jb359-5 Lab1]$ Bank.cpp:19: error: no match for ‘operator+=’ in ‘((Bank*)this)->Bank::checking += amount’
>   -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
>   [004709613@jb359-5 Lab1]$ Bank.cpp: In member function ‘void Bank::withdraw(double, std::string)’:
>   -bash: syntax error near unexpected token`('
>   [004709613@jb359-5 Lab1]$ Bank.cpp:26: error: no match for ‘operator-=’ in ‘((Bank*)this)->Bank::savings -= amount’
>   -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
>   [004709613@jb359-5 Lab1]$ Bank.cpp:28: error: no match for ‘operator-=’ in ‘((Bank*)this)->Bank::checking -= amount’
>   -bash: syntax error near unexpected token`('
>   [004709613@jb359-5 Lab1]$ Bank.cpp: In member function ‘void Bank::transfer(double, std::string)’:
>   -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
>   [004709613@jb359-5 Lab1]$ Bank.cpp:35: error: no match for ‘operator-=’ in ‘((Bank*)this)->Bank::savings -= amount’
>   -bash: syntax error near unexpected token`('
>   [004709613@jb359-5 Lab1]$ Bank.cpp:36: error: no match for ‘operator+=’ in ‘((Bank*)this)->Bank::checking += amount’
>   -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
>   [004709613@jb359-5 Lab1]$ Bank.cpp:38: error: no match for ‘operator-=’ in ‘((Bank*)this)->Bank::checking -= amount’
>   -bash: syntax error near unexpected token`('
>   [004709613@jb359-5 Lab1]$ Bank.cpp:39: error: no match for ‘operator+=’ in ‘((Bank*)this)->Bank::savings += amount’
>   -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
>   [004709613@jb359-5 Lab1]$ Bank.cpp: In member function ‘void Bank::print_balances()’:
>   -bash: syntax error near unexpected token`('
>   [004709613@jb359-5 Lab1]$ Bank.cpp:45: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::operator<< [with _Traits = std::char_traits](((std::basic_ostream >&)(& std::cout)), ((const char*)"Savings: $ ")) << ((Bank*)this)->Bank::savings’
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:108: note: candidates are: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:117: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:127: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:165: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:169: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:173: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(bool) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/ostream.tcc:91: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:180: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/ostream.tcc:105: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:191: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:200: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:204: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:209: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(double) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:213: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(float) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:221: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long double) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:225: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(const void*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/ostream.tcc:119: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   Bank.cpp:46: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::operator<< [with _Traits = std::char_traits](((std::basic_ostream >&)(& std::cout)), ((const char*)"Checking: $ ")) << ((Bank*)this)->Bank::checking’
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:108: note: candidates are: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:117: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:127: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:165: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:169: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:173: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(bool) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/ostream.tcc:91: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:180: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(short unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/ostream.tcc:105: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:191: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:200: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:204: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:209: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(double) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:213: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(float) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:221: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long double) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:225: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(const void*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/ostream.tcc:119: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  I'm sure it's something pretty stupid. I can post the header file as well, but it's difficult to do so due to remote editing issues.

Comment: Whatever type `savings` and `checking` are don't support such arithmetic or output.

Comment: Please post the header file so we can see what type `savings` is

Comment: You need to add a member function for operator+ which spells out what you want it to do.

Comment: To reiterate: what types are savings and checkings?  Bank.cpp line 17 is blank, are you sure the code you posted is exactly what you tried to compile?

Comment: Savings and checking are of type Account, which is another class I wrote, which compiled fine.  I feel like I'm doing something very obviously wrong here.  Also, line 17 in the Bank.cpp file is actually line 12 in the code I posted here.  I deleted out some comments at the top of the file that are required for my course.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You've written a lot of code, it doesn't work, and you don't know what's wrong. You can avoid this situation this way: start with something small and simple, add complexity a little at a time, test at every step, and *never add to code that doesn't work.*

Comment: Function transfer() is defined twice . What is the reason behind this or just a copy paste side effect.

Comment: Sorry, transfer() is defined twice because of a copy and paste error.  Still trying to figure this all out, but I should get it eventually.

Comment: Hah, love these diagnostics.

Answer (score 6):

You need to define the + operator for the Account class so it knows what to do. Since you were trying to add an Account object with a double, you would need this.

```
double Account::operator+(const double value) const {
    return balance + value;
}
```

If you want to add two account objects, you can overload with this.

```
Account Account::operator+(const Account &other) const {
    return Account(balance + other.balance, interest_rate);
}
```

Comment: `Account` does not have a constructor or `=` operator that accepts a single `double` as input, so the first operator  will not compile as you have shown it, since the result is assigned to an `Account`m so it needs an `Account` result. In the second operator, do not use `new`, and i would suggest using `this.interest_rate` instead of 0.

Comment: Yeah, realized that just after I posted it. Should be fixed now. Been coding so much in Java that I just typed new without thinking.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to add extra operators to your classes, then instead of writing:

```
savings = savings + amount;
```

use the already declared methods of the Account class and write:

```
savings.deposit(amount);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you declare saving and checking private members as "Account" rather than double. Even if that is your intended design, you can not add user defined class objects without expliclity define operator+(const Account &).

Answer (score 1):

In this line of your source code:

```
            savings = savings + amount;
```

`savings` has a type of `Account`, but `amount` is a `double`. Unless you define a `+` member operator on the `Account` class like

```
Account operator+(const double value) const;
```

Or a global `+` operator(possible as a `friend` function) like

```
Account operator+(const Account& account, const double value);
```

Then you cannot do such addition.